# Which iOS devices do not support iOS 5?

Tags: ios

What is the complete list of iOS devices (iPod Touch, iPhone, iPad) that are unable to update to iOS 5.0?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Devices not supported by iOS 5:

- iPhone (original)
- iPhone 3G
- iPod Touch first generation
- iPod Touch second generation
- AppleTV

Source: http://www.apple.com/ios/features.html . "iOS 5 is compatible with: iPhone 3GS, iPhone 4, iPhone 4S, iPod Touch 3rd generation, iPod Touch 4th generation, iPad, iPad 2."

Comment: AppleTV currently uses iOS 4.

Comment: Thanks, Ben! I'd also like to add that AppleTV can be considered a stand-alone product rather than a device that runs iOS.